# Paste a PDF-file into another PDF with ZendPDF

Tags: php, pdf, zend-pdf

Is it possible to "merge" or "paste" a PDF-file into antother PDF? Or must it be a image instead?

The PDF i want to to paste or merge, is a simple picture that is going to appear at the bottom of the finished PDF:

```
//Generate the "Original" PDF here..

function addReklam($reklamblad) //The PDF that should be merged into the PDF that is created above
    {

     //Count how many pages that has been created, and add it at the bottom of the PDF:

        if($this->drawed_lines<52)
        {
            $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[2];
        }
        elseif($this->drawed_lines<92)
        {
            $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[3];
        }
        elseif($this->drawed_lines<132)
        {
            $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[4];
        }
        else
        {
            $this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[5];
        }
        //$this->active_page = $this->pdf->pages[5];        // page 5 is the last
           //Add it here???         

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use the `Zend_Pdf::load()` method to load the "Original" PDF file into a local instance of `Zend_Pdf` and then you can access the pages using the `pages[]` array as in your sample code and use the all the standard functions like `drawImage()` etc to make the needed modifications prior to saving the updated version.